# Store "greater than or equal to" symbol in Oracle varchar2 column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a varchar2(255) column that I'd like to store a string like:

```
1 ≤ 2
```

However, when I run the following sql the ≤ symbol gets turned into a "=".

```
update my_table set my_column = '1 ≤ 2';
```

This results in the following value in my table:

```
1 = 2
```

How would I store a ≤ or ≥ in the database?

Comment: What character set are you using? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96529/ch2.htm#101203

Comment: Don't say, SHOW it. Please execute the following, `select * from table where column = '1 ≤ 2'` and copy paste the results here. Edit your post and add the results.

Comment: Lalit - executing that sql statement with "column = '1 ≥ 2'" or "column = '1 ≤ 2'" or even "column = '1 = 2'" will return the row in my initial update query. My question already contains the value that ends up in the database.

Comment: Regarding `character_set`, AFAIK, if `data type` is a `VARCHAR2, CHAR or CLOB` then the database default character set will be used. If it is `NVARCHAR, NCHAR or NCLOB` then the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`unistr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions224.htm#i1000165) to store UTF8 data.  It's not as convenient as a plain string, but it avoids errors caused by clients not interpreting UTF8 correctly.

```
--≥
select unistr('1 \2265 2') from dual;

--≤
select unistr('1 \2264 2') from dual;
```

Comment: Nice solution. But, OP's requirement is a rendering issue at first place, not a database one. Why use special characters, since they are not constant across the character sets.

Comment: @LalitKumarB It's difficult to know exactly where the string got garbled.  It could be either on the update or on the select.  Some clients, like PL/SQL Developer, will always display and retrieve UTF8 correctly, but won't send it correctly to the server.  [Those codes](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2264/index.htm) should work for either UTF8 or UTF16.  And if they're using ASCII7, meh, they deserve problems.  :)